# Byte[] Split Up Into 1022 Length Sections Then Restored Not Matching Up

Tags: c#, arrays, pdf

I am trying to take a PDF document and upload it via a MVC website to be stored into an SAP structure. The SAP structure requires the byte array to be broken up into 1022 length sections. The program seems to work good up to the point where I try to view the PDF document out of SAP. Unfortunately, I cannot view the PDF data stored in SAP due to access rights. So, I created a sort of MOCK program to match up the byte array from before it is sent to SAP (fileContent) and then what it should look like once it is returned from SAP (fileContentPostSAP).

The program compares the byte arrays and finds mismatching values at array location 1022.

Is there a bug in my program that is causing the byte arrays to not match? They are supposed to match exactly, right?

```
ClaimsIdentityMgr claimIdentityMgr = new ClaimsIdentityMgr();
ClaimsIdentity currentClaimsIdentity = claimIdentityMgr.GetCurrentClaimsIdentity();
var subPath = "~/App_Data/" + currentClaimsIdentity.EmailAddress;
var destinationPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(subPath), "LG WM3455H Spec Sheet.pdf");
byte[] fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(destinationPath);


//pretend this is going to SAP
var arrList = SAPServiceRequestRepository.CreateByteListForStructure(fileContent);
var mockStructureList = new List<byte[]>();
foreach (byte[] b in arrList)
     mockStructureList.Add(b);

//now get it back from Mock SAP
var fileContentPostSAP = new byte[fileContent.Count()];
var rowCounter = 0;
var prevLength = 0;
foreach (var item in mockStructureList)
{
    if (rowCounter == 0)
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(item, 0, fileContentPostSAP, 0, item.Length);
    else
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(item, 0, fileContentPostSAP, prevLength, item.Length);
    rowCounter++;
    prevLength = item.Length;
}

//compare the orginal array with the new one
var areEqual = (fileContent == fileContentPostSAP);
for (var i = 0; i < fileContent.Length; i++)
{
    if (fileContent[i] != fileContentPostSAP[i])
        throw new Exception("i = " + i + " | fileContent[i] = " + fileContent[i] + " | fileContentPostSAP[i] = " + fileContentPostSAP[i]);
}
```

And here is the CreateByteListForStructure function:

```
public static List<byte[]> CreateByteListForStructure(byte[] fileContent)
{
    var returnList = new List<byte[]>();

    for (var i = 0; i < fileContent.Length; i += 1022)
    {
        if (fileContent.Length - i >= 1022)
        {
            var localByteArray = new byte[1022];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(fileContent, i, localByteArray, 0, 1022);
            returnList.Add(localByteArray);
        }
        else
        {
            var localByteArray = new byte[fileContent.Length - i];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(fileContent, i, localByteArray, 0, fileContent.Length - i);
            returnList.Add(localByteArray);
        }
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this: `prevLength = item.Length;` be this? `prevLength += item.Length;` (notice the addition of the `+` sign before the `=` operator). Looks to me as though you're overwriting the start of the target array over and over again.

Comment: That was the bug. What do you think about adding that as an answer rather than a comment so I can mark it?

Comment: Posted more complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a simple bug in the code.

This loop, which reconstructs the contents of the array from the blocks:

```
var prevLength = 0;
foreach (var item in mockStructureList)
{
    if (rowCounter == 0)
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(item, 0, fileContentPostSAP, 0, item.Length);
    else
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(item, 0, fileContentPostSAP, prevLength, item.Length);
    rowCounter++;
    prevLength = item.Length;
}
```

By the description of the blocks, every block is 1022 bytes, which means that after the first iteration, `prevLength` is set to 1022, but after the next iteration it is set to 1022 *again*.

The more correct assignment of `prevLength` would be this:

```
prevLength += item.Length;
           ^
           |
           +-- added this
```

This will correctly move the pointer in the output array forward one block at a time, instead of moving it to the second block and then leaving it there.

Basically you write block 0 in the correct place, but all the other blocks on top of block 1, leaving block 2 and onwards in the output array as zeroes.